# Make data pulled from a remote source available in NodeJS App

Tags: node.js, express, salesforce

I'm just getting going with NodeJS and am trying to use jsforce (salesforce) to populate a dropdown on a form.

I've written a module the requires jsforce, sets login params, and connects.

```
``modules/sftools.js
const jsforce = require('jsforce')
const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
  loginUrl: process.env.SF_LOGINURL
})
conn.login(process.env.SF_USER, process.env.SF_PASS)

exports.metaDropDown = async (field) => 
  conn.sobject...describe..
  return arrayOfValues
}
```

I want to make the value returned available throughout my app, so in index.js I've got

```
``index.js
const sftools= require('../modules/sftools')
const roles = sftools.metaDropDown(process.env.SF_ROLES)
```

and then I use some middleware to always set req.roles = roles.

I think the problem is that I'm requesting the roles before the connection is established, but I can't figure out the flow.

I tried logging in before the exports code, but I get an Invalid URL error, presumably because it isn't logged in yet.
I tried to put the login code directly into the metaDropdown export, which got rid of the error, but there is still no data returned.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue your having is that for the login function is expecting a callback as the third argument.

```
conn.login(process.env.SF_USER, process.env.SF_PASS, function() {
    // do your role logic here.
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Still not getting what I want though (probably coming from a php background...) but how could I put my logic in there if I want the methods exported as modules? Or do I need to wrap every interaction with JSForce in an async/await login - and does that mean I can't grab it once in a middleware and make it available throughout?

Comment: What do you mean by middleware?  Do you want to take to a chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147287/middleware